# Transform the keys to list, I got a problem type error in dictionary data type

Tags: python, typeerror

I set the dictionary data type like this.

```
a={'name':'pey','phone':'0101111','birth':'1111'}
```

and I want to transform the key to list.

So, I command in iDle like this.

```
list(a.keys())
```

I expect this result as

```
['name','phone','birth']
```

But, I have error this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<pyshell#188>", line 1, in <module> list(a.keys()) TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How I get the result? ( Key -> list ).
Thanks to watch my question.

Comment: Have you earlier in your script used the name `list` for one of your lists? If so, you've overwritten the in-built `list` function and caused this error. Just use a different name.

Comment: The code you included in your question is working fine for me, so please check what @RobinZigmond said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply  do this. create an empty list `lst=[]` and iterate dictionaries keys and append it in list one by one

```
a={'name':'pey','phone':'0101111','birth':'1111'}
lst=[]
for i in a.keys():
    lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```

Output.

```
['name','phone','birth']
```

Comment: `a.keys()` will not return a list, it will return `<class 'dict_keys'>`

Comment: Just do `list(a.keys())`

Comment: See the comments, this returns an error because the OP had overwritten the built-in `list` function earlier in their code. Your answer alone should not return an error.

Comment: I have solution in your comment! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
list(a.keys())
```

a.keys() was already returning list. So you can just use the following

```
a.keys()
```

and BTW list() is not the python way to create a list. Checkout this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list) for to know more.

Comment: I have solution in your answer. Thanks a lot